# A property of integrals

Tags: calculus

> Let $f,g$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and suppose $g(x) \geq 0
>  $ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Prove there exists $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that
>
> $$ \int\limits_a^b f(x) g(x) \mathrm{d} x = f( \xi ) \int\limits_a^b
>  g(x) \mathrm{d} x $$

My attempt:

Mean value theorem says we can find some $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that

$$ \int\limits_a^b f(x) g(x) \mathrm{d} x = f(\xi ) g (\xi) (b-a)  $$

Here I want to also apply the MVT to $\int_a^b g(x) dx $ but this does not seem to help since this will give a different $\xi$. Am I on the right track or should I use other tactics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(x)=0$ identically on $[a,b]$, then
$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=\int_a^b g(x)dx=0$$
and so any $\xi\in[a,b]$ works.

Otherwise, we can guarantee that $\int_a^b g(x)dx>0$. Let $m=\min\limits_{[a,b]}f(x)$ and $M=\max\limits_{[a,b]} f(x)$. Show that
$$m\le \frac{\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_a^b g(x)dx}\le M$$
and you're done by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Here is how I would show the inequality you propose: Since $ g(x) m \leq f(x) \leq g(x) M$, then

$$ m \int_a^b g \leq \int_a^b fg \leq M \int_a^b g $$

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Yes, except for the middle part of the "Since..." inequality must be $g(x)f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the MVT to the function
$$
h(x)=\frac{1}{\int_a^bg(u)\,du}\,\int_a^xf(t)g(t)\,dt
$$

Comment: Good point! Edited.